# Capistrano 3 Wordpress deployment with cap staging deploy on bitbucket fails

Tags: wordpress, deployment, staging, capistrano3

I am trying to do a Capistrano 3 deploy for my Wordpress setup [as per this screencast](http://roots.io/screencasts/deploying-wordpress-with-capistrano/)
I am deploying to an ubuntu 12.04 server

So here is my deploy.rb file:

```
set :application, 'dladv'
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:username/repo.git'

set :branch, proc { `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp }

set :deploy_via, :copy
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/php/domain' # I have set the correct permissions with www:data group and added stager as member of this group

set :log_level, :debug
set :pty, true

set :linked_dirs, %w{uploads}

# set :default_env, {}


namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app) do
      sudo "apache2ctl", "graceful", "-v"
    end
  end

end
```

And my `staging.rb` looks like this:

```
set :stage, :staging

server 'staging.domain.com', user: 'stager', roles: %w{web app db}, port: 47

# set it globally
set :ssh_options, {
 keys: %w(/home/stager/.ssh/id_rsa),
 forward_agent: true,
 auth_methods: %w(password)
}
```

Now when I try to do `cap staging deploy --trace`, I get:

```
→ cap staging deploy --trace
** Invoke staging (first_time)
** Execute staging
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke deploy:starting (first_time)
** Execute deploy:starting
** Invoke deploy:check (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check
** Invoke git:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper (first_time)
** Execute git:wrapper
 INFO [217d8451] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/dladv/ on staging.domain.com
DEBUG [217d8451] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/dladv/
cap aborted!
Authentication failed for user stager@staging.domain.com
/Users/amiterandole/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/net-ssh-2.8.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:217:in `start'
/Users/amiterandole/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:25:in `create_or_reuse_connection'
/Users/amiterandole/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:173:in `ssh'
/Users/amiterandole/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:126:in `block in _execute'
/Users/amiterandole/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:123:in `tap'
/Users/amiterandole/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:123:in `_execute'
/Users/amiterandole/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/Users/amiterandole/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/amiterandole/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/Users/amiterandole/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/Users/amiterandole/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => git:check => git:wrapper
```

1. I have added my imac's `ssh/id_ra.pub` key to the server's `authorized_keys` file and
2. I have generated  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@gmail.com"` on the server and then added that key to both my github account and my bitbucket account
3. I have verfied with bitbucket on the server with `ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org`

I don't know why it keeps saying `Authentication failed for user stager@staging.domain.com`
Please help

Comment: Is your ssh key correct in server ?

Comment: This has happened to me several times—after successfully deploy for weeks on end, and I still can't find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

```ruby
set :user, 'your_deploy_user_name'

set :ssh_options, {
   user: fetch(:user)
}
```

this works for me